# Why do I have multiple entries per entity in the query output?

Tags: sql, ssms

Would like to know why my query displays multiple entries per entity in the output.
From what I understand there is only one active policy per entity.

Created query with SQL Server Management Studio, my output to display correctly has parameters, and I have tried the following with my query.

Currently my SQL SSMS query output displays the following:

```
Entity_Number  Building_Name PolicyID  Description         Start_Date   End_Date
 400           Xpress         4         5 Day Grace        7/1/2019     9/27/2019
 400           Xpress         18        2 Day Grace        7/3/2018     7/13/2018
 400           Xpress         19        4 Day Grace        2/27/2019    2/27/2019
```

What I really would like to know is how do I drill down and find out why my query returns multiples?

[Query]

```
SELECT
e.Entity_Number,
bld.Building_Name,
cbp.PolicyId, 
cbp.Description,  
cbp.StartDate, 
cbp.EndDate

FROM            
dbo.buildings AS bld
INNER JOIN dbo.entities AS e
ON bld.Entity_ID = e.Entity_ID 
INNER JOIN Collections.Building AS cbp
ON bld.Building_ID = cb.BuildingId
INNER JOIN Collections.BuildingProfile AS cbpro
ON cbp.BuildingPolicyId = cbpro.BuildingPolicyId

WHERE
bld.Building_Active = 1
AND e.Active = 1
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided sample data and expected output, but I'm not sure I understand the question. Your results only seem to have one entity (400) and one building (Xpress). The multiple rows seem to be from `cbp`.

Comment: It's going to be from one or more of your inner joins. Examine the execution plan and see which join is outputting more than 1 row. Then Bob is your proverbial.

Comment: It also helps if you don't estimate the SQL.  It needs to be correct, without errors. Notice: `cbp` does not exist in the `FROM` clause.  You're either missing a `JOIN` or mistyped something.

Comment: @Jon Armstrong, Oops, corrected 'cbp' on inner join, all exists now.

Comment: Explain this logic carefully:`INNER JOIN Collections.Building AS cbp ON bld.Building_ID = cb.BuildingId`

Comment: Complete the question with `CREATE TABLE` statements and `INSERT` statements that, based on your exact query, produce the mysterious result.  Use dbfiddle.uk to provide the working test case.

Comment: The updated SQL is still invalid (the cb table / alias, as in `cb.BuildingId`, is not found), as I mentioned.  Until that's corrected, the question is not directly answerable.  Once corrected, data may be required to find the logic mistake / data misunderstanding. __Always test your test case and SQL, to be sure it executes and produced the unexpected result.__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "salami technique" to isolate where the unexpected rows come from. What I mean by this is that you cut down the query like a salami by omitting each join (and any column references related to that join) one by one.

e.g. start with masking the join to `Collections.BuildingProfile`:

```
SELECT
      e.Entity_Number
    , bld.Building_Name
    , cbp.PolicyId
    , cbp.Description
    , cbp.StartDate
    , cbp.EndDate
FROM dbo.buildings AS bld
INNER JOIN dbo.entities AS e ON bld.Entity_ID = e.Entity_ID
INNER JOIN Collections.Building AS cbp ON bld.Building_ID = cbp.BuildingId
-- INNER JOIN Collections.BuildingProfile AS cbpro ON cbp.BuildingPolicyId = cbpro.BuildingPolicyId
WHERE bld.Building_Active = 1
    AND e.Active = 1
```

Does this remove the unexpected columns? If not then try:

```
SELECT
      e.Entity_Number
    , bld.Building_Name
    --, cbp.PolicyId
    --, cbp.Description
    --, cbp.StartDate
    --, cbp.EndDate
FROM dbo.buildings AS bld
INNER JOIN dbo.entities AS e ON bld.Entity_ID = e.Entity_ID
--INNER JOIN Collections.Building AS cbp ON bld.Building_ID = cbp.BuildingId
--INNER JOIN Collections.BuildingProfile AS cbpro ON cbp.BuildingPolicyId = cbpro.BuildingPolicyId
WHERE bld.Building_Active = 1
    AND e.Active = 1
```

Eventually by masking out each join (and any related column references to that table) you will discover which table is producing the unexpected multiplication of rows.

Once that table is identified I suggest you **reconsider all assumptions** you have made about how that table had been joined. For example, you state that *" From what I understand there is only one active policy per entity."*  **Is that really true?**

Once you know where the problem starts, and you reconsider how that data should actually be used within the query, you should be closer to a solution. e.g. perhaps you need more conditions in the join, or you need to join a subquery instead of directly to the table.

Note:

- Collections.BuildingProfile does not seem needed by the query, why not omit it
  anyway?
- reformatting for "comma first" in the select clause helps simplify use of the  "salami technique"